# MySQL: get the total query number after grouping and counting

Tags: mysql, count

I have a below query:

```
select count(*) c , id 
from hr 
where  time >= '2011-11-8 00:00:00' and 
       time <= '2011-12-9 23:59:59' 
group by id 
having c>3;
```

The result list could be very huge (up to 10,000 items sometime), I don't want to list all since I only want to get the total number. Apart from "select found_rows()", I'm trying to  find one sql sentence to get the job done without printing the list. (I'm not using Perl, PHP or any other API, just sql)

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Yang

Comment: Just the question and answer I needed! Sweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a subquery and count the records again

```
SELECT COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM
(
    select count(*) c , id 
    from hr 
    where  time >= '2011-11-8 00:00:00' and 
           time <= '2011-12-9 23:59:59' 
    group by id 
    having COUNT(*) > 3
) x
```

Comment: You are right. I used sub select, but I didn't know the "x" was needed. Thanks again.

Comment: `x` is an alias of the derieved table :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT id, COUNT(*) c FROM hr WHERE time >= '2011-11-8 00:00:00' AND time <= '2011-12-9 23:59:59' GROUP BY id) counts WHERE counts.c > 3;
```